# How to put a table in the report header?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to generate a report that has a solid legend table on top.

I've tried to put it in the header section, so it wouldn't scroll down with the page 
but I can't put any table inside the header

Answer (score 2):

comment:
As per Ed Harper, but maybe use a rectangle for containment of text boxes?

--
"Commenting requires 50 reputation"
Ok, i'll just clog up the thread with an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to put a series of text boxes in the header and arrange them manually into a "table".

Assuming your legend isn't data-driven, this shouldn't be too difficult - particularly if you use the Format > Horizontal/Vetical Spacing > Remove tool when laying the fields out.

Answer (score 1):

If you do need your legend to be data driven it might be best to put your legend in the the main body and not use the report header.

It can still be configured to display on every page etc.

I've found that to be the best approach for data driven header information.